# PyQGIS: How to send signal if layer is currently in edit mode

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm looking for a way to send a signal if a layer is in editing mode. I tried editingStarted(), but it wasn't working. I'd like to do something along the lines of the what I have below, but can't find it in the API (where I'm looking: http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a476eaf6ec8f2a45e285e963bcacedcc2)

```
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(myLayer)
#capslock is in place of the method i'm searching
if myLayer.ISINEDITMODE() == False:
    qgis.utils.iface.actionToggleEditing().trigger()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the **isEditable** method:

```
if not myLayer.isEditable():
    iface.actionToggleEditing.trigger()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're after the signal you define it like this:

```
layer.editingStarted.connect(yourfunction)
```